# Open native Spotify app from mobile browser

Tags: android, ios, spotify, mobile-browser

Is it possible to click a link to a users profile in a mobile web browser on Android/iOS and have the Spotify native app open.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some investigation, to open the native Spotify app on either mobile or desktop just replace

the URL:

`https://play.spotify.com/user/user_Id/playlist/playlist_Id`

with the URI:

`spotify:user:user_Id:playlist:playlist_Id`

I have only tested this on Chrome and Android. But I think it should work on iOS as well.

Answer (score 0):

This happens autonomously, provided the user has the app installed

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on Android 4.1, using Chrome and the latest Spotify release. For example, clicking https://play.spotify.com/user/<user_ID>/ will redirect to the Spotify homepage through Chrome.

Comment: Spotify url scheme automatically detects if the user has the app installed, however if it's not working then you will have to force open it with code in the website backend, if you don't have control over the website backend then there is little you can do without some serious coding. I would suggest simply creating a button or label that you have control over

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'll give it a go and see what I can do.