# Open native Spotify App from Cordova (App)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, spotify

Hello and good morning,

i tried to open the spotify app from my cordova app....

i found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391725/open-native-spotify-app-from-mobile-browser) but it cant help me.

This is my code:

```
appAvailability.check(
                        'com.spotify.music',
                        function () {  // Success callback
                            window.open('https://open.spotify.com/track/3n3Ppam7vgaVa1iaRUc9Lp', '_system', 'location=no');
                        },
                        function () {  // Error callback
                            window.open('http://google.de', '_system', 'location=no');
                        }
                );
```

I tried the code from the thread above. I tried:

```
spotify:user:user_Id:playlist:playlist_Id
spotify://user:user_Id:playlist:playlist_Id
spotify://user/user_Id/playlist/playlist_Id
```

nothing works..i can only open spotify with inappbrowser. But i cant open the native spotify app.... i hope someone could help me